# ArcGIS/Server can not display the digital places as ArcGIS/desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-server

The number of decimal places can be set in ArcGIS desktop as shown in the screenshot. 
[image]

However, ArcGIS server fails to do this.
[image]

What could be the issue here? How can I reflect the displayed digital places from the desktop to the server?

Comment: You're looking at the HTML output of a REST request.  Fetch it in JSON and format it as you require.

Answer (score 2):

When you change the number of decimal places in ArcMap you are changing the *display* of the number not actually truncating it. So if the original number had 8 decimal places it still has 8 decimal places even if you chose to display it as 3.

I would say this display is a property of a *Layer object* and not a *Feature Class*, so if you are displaying data direct from a Feature Class in ArcServer then it is not surprising that you are seeing the full number of decimal places. You need to be viewing a Layer object from ArcServer if you want to impose a restriction on the number of decimal places. I don't use ArcServer so I leave that to someone else to answer.

Comment: Thank you Shiko and Hornbyadd for your replies. I guess it is a need to control the number of decimals places in ArcGIS server. I hope that someone who uses ArcGIS server can help on this.

Answer (score 1):

The Number format is reflected on **ArcGIS Desktop** because it is converting the value from original column **SHAPE_AREA** but ArcGIS Server shows the raw data without applying any settings. My suggestion is to create a new field in same layer and use the **Field Calculator** to add the processed value.